# Can we communicate client and server using SOAP UI in Android?

Tags: android

provide any related links.
If yes it's fine. If NO why? suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what exactly you mean. SOAP UI itself is a windows application. Android of course can communicate with a server using SOAP messages.

I don't want to be rude, but spending a bit more time on the question would help others to be motivated to answer as well make it easier to find the answer you are looking for.